# Trim spaces from start and end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find a way to trim spaces from the start and end of the title string. I was using this, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
title = title.replace(/(^[\s]+|[\s]+$)/g, '');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: var s = ' 1 '; s = s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); alert('-' + s + '-'); // it works like this, you dont need the parens or square braces.

Comment: Javascript has `.trim` built in now, so this is answer for modern browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3000900/29182

Comment: Refer this article: http://javascriptstutorial.com/blog/trim-string/

Comment: `function trim11 (str) {
    str = str.replace(/^\s+/, '');
    for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (/\S/.test(str.charAt(i))) {
            str = str.substring(0, i + 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    return str;
}`

Answer (score 223):

Note: As of 2015, [all major browsers (including IE>=9) support String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim#Browser_compatibility). This means that for most use cases simply doing `str.trim()` is the best way of achieving what the question asks.

---

Steven Levithan analyzed many different implementation of `trim` in Javascript in terms of performance.

His recommendation is:

```
function trim1 (str) {
    return str.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
}
```

for "general-purpose implementation which is fast cross-browser", and

```
function trim11 (str) {
    str = str.replace(/^\s+/, '');
    for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (/\S/.test(str.charAt(i))) {
            str = str.substring(0, i + 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

"if you want to handle long strings exceptionally fast in all browsers".

#### References

- [blog.stevenlevithan.com -- Faster JavaScript Trim](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript)

Comment: The new Safari (5), Chrome(5), Firefox(3.6) and Opera (10.5) all support a native String trim method. That being the case, I'd assign a method to String.prototype, if it does not exist, rather than a new  global function.

Comment: `String.prototype.trim = String.prototype.trim || function trim() { return this.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, ''); };`

Comment: I doubt that after recent improvements on javascript performance this test is still relevant or reliable as it was at the time of this answer.

Comment: why are you using double white characters ? aka why this regex `/^\s\s*/` and not this one `/^\s*/`

Comment: Why `trim1` and `trim11`?

Comment: aemonge -- not having seen the behind the scenes, matching a character is probably a lot faster than matching a character or null, and your alternative will trigger the replace which can also be expensive.  Or both.

Answer (score 69):

If using jQuery is an option:

```
/**
 * Trim the site input[type=text] fields globally by removing any whitespace from the
 * beginning and end of a string on input .blur()
 */
$('input[type=text]').blur(function(){
    $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
});
```

or simply:

```
$.trim(string);
```

Answer (score 48):

As [@ChaosPandion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000649/trim-spaces-from-start-and-end-of-string/3000676#3000676) mentioned, the `String.prototype.trim` method has been introduced into the [ECMAScript 5th Edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) Specification, [some implementations](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) already include this method, so the best way is to detect the native implementation and declare it *only* if it's not available:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.trim != 'function') { // detect native implementation
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');
  };
}
```

Then you can simply:

```
title = title.trim();
```

Comment: I'm always a little bemused by this meme of checking if the property is a function. If it's not a function is the right behavior really to overwrite it? Perhaps you should throw an error in that case.

Comment: @kojiro, well, maybe throwing an error would be good, but I see it like this: I'm trying to make an *spec-compliant shim*, and if `String.prototype.trim` is not a function, it *is not* the `String.prototype.trim` method described on the ECMAScript 5th Edition Specification, the spec guarantees that `trim` is a function object on ES5 environments.

Comment: `throw { name: "UnlikelyPolyfillException", message: "Did someone really write a property on the String prototype named 'trim' that isn't a ECMA 5 compatible shim? Come on now, that's crazy." }`

Answer (score 35):

I know this is an old post, but just thought I'd share our solution. In the quest for shortest code (doesn't everyone just *love* terse regex), one could instead use:

```
title = title.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '');
```

BTW: I ran this same test through the link shared above [blog.stevenlevithan.com -- Faster JavaScript Trim](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript) and this pattern beat all the other HANDS down!

Using IE8, added test as test13. The results were:

> Original length: 226002
>   trim1: 110ms (length: 225994)
>   trim2: 79ms (length: 225994)
>   trim3: 172ms (length: 225994)
>   trim4: 203ms (length:225994)
>   trim5: 172ms (length: 225994)
>   trim6: 312ms (length: 225994)
>   trim7: 203ms (length: 225994)
>   trim8: 47ms (length: 225994)
>   trim9: 453ms (length: 225994)
>   trim10: 15ms (length: 225994)
>   trim11: 16ms (length: 225994)
>   trim12: 31ms (length: 225994)
>   trim13: 0ms (length: 226002)

Answer (score 11):

ECMAScript 5 supports `trim` and this has been implemented in Firefox.

[trim - MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Answer (score 11):

Here, this should do all that you need

```
function doSomething(input) {
    return input
              .replace(/^\s\s*/, '')     // Remove Preceding white space
              .replace(/\s\s*$/, '')     // Remove Trailing white space
              .replace(/([\s]+)/g, '-'); // Replace remaining white space with dashes
}

alert(doSomething("  something with  some       whitespace   "));
```

Comment: \s\s* seems redundant, since there is \s+, but it's a little bit faster

Answer (score 4):

Here is some methods I've been used in the past to trim strings in js:

```
String.prototype.ltrim = function( chars ) {
    chars = chars || "\\s*";
    return this.replace( new RegExp("^[" + chars + "]+", "g"), "" );
}

String.prototype.rtrim = function( chars ) {
    chars = chars || "\\s*";
    return this.replace( new RegExp("[" + chars + "]+$", "g"), "" );
}
String.prototype.trim = function( chars ) {
    return this.rtrim(chars).ltrim(chars);
}
```

Comment: The RegExp `^[\s*]+` matches `*` at the beginning of the string, so that your function trims `"*** Foo"` to `"Foo"`.

Comment: probably :) wonder why no one have complained... It was a long time ago I wrote that code, and it's used in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Twinkle . off source now that you point it out it's obvious.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my current code, the 2nd line works if I comment the 3rd line, but don't work if I leave it how it is.

```
var page_title = $(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/g, '');
page_title = page_title.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
page_title = page_title.replace(/([\s]+)/g, '-');
```

Comment: remove 2nd & third line, and use the code from polygenelubricants, page_title = trim1(page_title);

Comment: so ultimately you're trying to clean this string to be trimmed, alpha-numeric, and dashes instead of spaces as separators?

Comment: @chad yes. To create slug URLs on the fly so users can see what their URL will look like. Similar to how wordpress does it when creating new blog posts.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `string.trim()` method. It's supported by all major browsers.
Reference here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

Answer (score 2):

jQuery.trim("    hello, how are you?    ");

:)

Comment: Looks like you might be making a funny, but keep in mind people reading this comment might be tempted to use your solution and move along.

Comment: $.trim("   blabh blah blah "); 
correctly returns "blabh blah blah"

Answer (score 2):

```
var word = " testWord ";   //add here word or space and test

var x = $.trim(word);

if(x.length > 0)
    alert('word');
else
    alert('spaces');
```

Answer (score 2):

When the DOM is fully loaded, you can add this to all the text fields. I have never had a situation where I needed to submit leading or trailing space, so doing it all the time globally has worked for me...

```
$(function() { $('input[type=text]').on('blur', function(){
    $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
  });
});
```

Comment: requires jQuery. Another question (I didn't test it): does `blur` actually occur before the submit when i'm in a fields and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to send a form?

Answer (score 2):

This is what is suggested by JavaScript Architect/Guru Douglas Crockford.

```
String.method('trim', function (  ) {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
});
```

Note: you have to define "method" for Function.prototype.

### Alternatively

```
String.prototype.trim = function () {
   return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
};

title.trim();    // returns trimmed title
```

### Observation

In recent browsers, the *trim* method is included by default. So you don't have to add it explicitly.

Major browsers Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc. supports *trim* method.
Checked in Chrome 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit), Firefox 51.0.1 (64-bit), Safari 10.0 (12602.1.50.0.10).

Answer (score 0):

a recursive try for this

```
function t(k){ 
    if (k[0]==' ') {
        return t(k.substr(1,k.length));
    } else if (k[k.length-1]==' ') {
        return t(k.substr(0,k.length-1));
    } else {
        return k;
    }
}
```

call like this:

```
t("      mehmet       "); //=>"mehmet"
```

if you want to filter spesific chars you can define a list string basically:

```
function t(k){
    var l="\r\n\t "; //you can add more chars here.
    if (l.indexOf(k[0])>-1) {
        return t(k.substr(1,k.length));
    } else if (l.indexOf(k[k.length-1])>-1) {
        return t(k.substr(0,k.length-1));
    } else {
        return k;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a subtle difference from what's being asked! You are checking for a space `' '`, but the question is about white space in general, including `"\n"`, `"\t"` and other non printable characters that are matched in regex by `/\s/`.

Comment: then you can edit if condition as " if("\t\r\n ".indexOf(k[0])>-1)" still it works, those are certain types already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trimLeft()` and `trimRight()` also.

```
const str1 = "   string   ";
console.log(str1.trimLeft()); 
// => "string   "

const str2 = "   string   ";
console.log(str2.trimRight());
// => "    string"
```