# JavaScript's regexp - new lines and empty spaces at the end of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trim spaces from start and end of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000649/trim-spaces-from-start-and-end-of-string)

I would like to find a way to achieve the following results:

```
"I am\n a string \n\n  \n \n".replace(/\n{1,}$/g,""); // "I am\n a string"
```

What is the best way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
"I am\n a string \n\n  \n \n".replace(/\s+$/,""); // "I am\n a string"
```

should do the job.

`\s` is a whitespace character including Space, Tab, Newlines

`+` is the same quantifier as `{1,}`

Comment: The `\s` character class includes **tab**, **line feed**, **form feed**, **carriage return**, and **space**.

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```
   "I am a string \n\n  \n \n".replace(/\s+$/g, "")
```