# How to Use xmlhttp.responseText in If condition?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

This is my save_custLog_data.php file.

```
<?php
    $a = $_GET['custEmail'];
    $b = $_GET['pswrd'];
    $file = '/home/students/accounts/s2090031/hit3324/www/data/customer.xml';

    if(file_exists($file))
    {

        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($file, null, true);

        foreach($xml->children() as $child)
        {

            if((($child->EmailAddress) == $email) && (($child->Password) == $password))
            {

                if(isset($session))
                {
                    $session = (string)$child->CustId;
                    $_SESSION['cust_id'] = $session;
                    echo"Welcome";

                }
        break;

             }
     else
             {
                    echo"Invalid Email or Password!! Please Enter again";
                    exit();
      }
        }

}
else
{
    echo"XML file you are trying to access doesn't exist";
}


?>
```

above is my php page. below you can see my html page. But I'll just add only the embeded javascript part only.

```
<script>
    function validate()
{
    var email = "";
    var pswrd = "";

    email = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;
    pswrd = document.getElementById("txtPaswrd").value;


    if((email != "") && (pswrd != ""))
    {
         if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
         {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
           xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
         }
         else
         {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                var msg = xmlhttp.responseText;
                if(msg == "Welcome")
                {
                    window.location.assign("buying.htm");//this method call doesn't work
                }
                else
                {
                    alert(msg);
                }


            }
         }

         xmlhttp.open("GET","save_custLog_data.php?custEmail="+email+"&pswrd="+pswrd,true);
         xmlhttp.send();

    }
    else
    {
        alert("Loging form can't be empty");
    }

}
</script>
```

So my question why is that window.location.assign("buying.htm") method call doesn't work

Comment: The command itself is working - are you sure the conditional get fulfilled? Did you check that with debugger or console.log()?

Comment: I think the if condition doesn't work at all. Only the "else" part is working. So instead i redirect to the specified page I get a alert msg.

Comment: I found the answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000649/trim-spaces-from-start-and-end-of-string

Answer (score 0):

Prepend a slash

```
window.location.assign('/buying.htm');
```

Comment: I tried this but still not working. Btw I edited the question a bit.