# How to remove whitespace and new line, only at beginning of textarea

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove whitespace and new line, only at the beginning. I want some suggestions, I am using the following code.

```
var myTxtArea = document.getElementById('visionText');
myTxtArea.value = myTxtArea.value.replace(/^s|^n/g, '');
```

Comment: [`.replace(/^[\s\r\n]+/g, '')`](https://regex101.com/r/tB4xP3/1)

Comment: `/^s|^n/` matches if the first character is a `s` or `n`.

Comment: Please use the search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+trim+start+string .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trim spaces from start and end of string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000649/trim-spaces-from-start-and-end-of-string)

Answer (score 2):

```js
alert(" \n\n    I am a string \n  starting with whitespace and newline");
alert(" \n\n    I am a string with no starting whitespace and newline".replace(/^\s+/, ""));
```

```
var reg = /^\s|\n/g;

var str = " asdfkadsf[xxxxx]bb";

var test = str.replace(reg,"") ;
```

Try this as well

```
" \n\n    I am a string  ".replace(/^\s+/,"");
```

Answer (score -3):

Ok, you will try to use the function trim, that function remove the white spaces and new line from the begining and the end

var myTxtArea = document.getElementById('visionText');
myTxtArea.value = myTxtArea.value.trim();

Comment: note the very subtle hint in the original question: `only at the beginning`