# Email regex allow spaces in validation

Tags: javascript, email

Ok, so I needed an email validator with Javascript. So, I used the code from this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/6540373). The problem involves putting a space *after* your email address. If I enter `example@gmail.com`, nothing wrong happens. If I enter `example@gmail.com`, notice the added space at the end, the email address is proved invalid. People make mistakes and an added space shouldn't deem an email address invalid. How do I fix this...

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}

function validate() {
  $("#result").text("");
  var email = $("#email").val();
  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $("#result").text(email + " is valid :)");
    $("#result").css("color", "green");
  } else {
    $("#result").text(email + " is not valid :(");
    $("#result").css("color", "red");
  }
  return false;
}

$("form").bind("submit", validate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <p>Enter an email address:</p>
  <input id='email'>
  <button type='submit' id='validate'>Validate!</button>
</form>

<h2 id='result'></h2>
```

Comment: `var email = $("#email").val().trim();` might suffice. See [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3000900/5781248)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add ***`\s*`***.  The character **`\s`** will simply match a single white space character and **`*`** will match it ***0 - nth*** times.

You will want to place this after *`/^(...{2,})) ***insert \s* here *** $/`*;

Here is the complete updated line:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^\s*(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))\s*$/;
```

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^\s*(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))\s*$/;
  return re.test(email);
}

function validate() {
  $("#result").text("");
  var email = $("#email").val();
  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $("#result").text(email + " is valid :)");
    $("#result").css("color", "green");
  } else {
    $("#result").text(email + " is not valid :(");
    $("#result").css("color", "red");
  }
  return false;
}

$("form").bind("submit", validate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <p>Enter an email address:</p>
  <input id='email'>
  <button type='submit' id='validate'>Validate!</button>
</form>

<h2 id='result'></h2>
```