# Simple if statment not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple code which is supposed to work but it isn't working. The if statement never seems to be true.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var country = "United States";

  $.each($('select[name="country"]').children('option'), function(){
    if($(this).text() == country){
      alert("found");
    }else{
      console.log("Not found");
    }

  });

});
```

HTML:

```
<select name="country"  value="" >
  <option value="0" >Afghanistan </option>
  <option value="1" >Albania </option>
  <option value="2" >Algeria </option>
  <option value="3" >American Samoa </option>
  .
  .
  .
  .
```

I get no errors in the console.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftLa6dyf/)

Comment: remove spaces after text in option

Comment: The problem is the spaces, but the normal way to do this is compare number IDs, not text that can be different (tildes, uppercases, spaces, etc). So all answers here will be fine but your code still will be inconsistent and dangerously wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your option values have a trailing space `" "`, so they do not match your `country` (which has no trailing space).

```
"United States" != "United States "
```

Note: You could have easily debugged this by adding a breakpoint and checking both values.

---

Possible Solutions:

1. Trim the `text()` result before you compare it (**recommended**)
2. Remove the spaces from within the HTML (I would do this too anyway)
3. Add an extra space to the `country` value (nonsense... but does work)

---

**Recommended Solution**

```
if($(this).text().trim() == country){
    alert("found");
}
```

You may want to check the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) for the `trim()` function to ensure it matches your requirements. If it doesn't, then you may find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3000784/838807) of some interest.

Comment: Nice catch! I will be trimming both the arguments since some countries contain a space e.g('UnitedStates' != 'United States' )

Comment: @user3284463: `trim` will only remove leading and trailing whitespace, it won't remove any spaces in between words. Though depending on where you really get `country` from, it might make sense to trim both anyway

Answer (score 2):

Use trim function in your if condition

`if($.trim($(this).text()) == country)`

Comment: Thanks!. I ended up trimming both value `if($.trim($(this).text()) == $.trim(country))`