# Trim name in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var name="james            mark";
var name="james           " ;
```

so how to trim both the names occur any condition from this anytime  in javascript

Output:

**james mark**

**james**

Comment: Please provide some examples of what you already tried or where you are stuck.

Comment: @MrMins That isn't what this question is asking.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen too many similar questions already asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000649/trim-spaces-from-start-and-end-of-string

Comment: @revo there absolutely are, but not the one that was selected as a duplicate.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen So cast your close vote instead of adding to duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace all instances of repeated white space with a single space and also trim all leading and trailing white space:

```
name.replace(/\s+/g,' ');
name.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''); // or use .trim()
```

for more information you should read the description on the [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) functions on MDN

Comment: I would keep it simple by using .trim (as I see an edit suggests as I'm writing this) and also note that you can do these inline: .replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()

Comment: Thxxiee can you tell me for second one in that case we don't require space so solution is name.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''); this one

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var name="james            mark";
var j = names.split(' ');
alert(j[0]);

//The otput: James (without the blank spaces)
```

Comment: var str="Angle             aaaaa         "; what will do in this case  OUTPUT: Angle aaaaa